# Why DragLeave event isn't fired when node dragged out of TreeView?

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop, treeview, nodes

As I read in other questions, mostly peoples asks why it firing unexpectedly, but for me it never fires at all.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestDrag
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            treeView1.ItemDrag += treeView1_ItemDrag;
            treeView1.DragLeave += treeView1_DragLeave;

            groupBox1.AllowDrop = true;
            groupBox1.DragEnter += groupBox1_DragEnter;
            groupBox1.DragDrop += groupBox1_DragDrop;

            treeView1.Nodes.Add("asd");
            treeView1.Nodes.Add("dsa");
        }

        void groupBox1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        void groupBox1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
        }

        void treeView1_ItemDrag(object sender, ItemDragEventArgs e)
        {
            treeView1.DoDragDrop(e.Item, DragDropEffects.Copy);
        }

        void treeView1_DragLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(this, "This message never shows when node dragged out of treeView1", "This is bad", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to hide TreeView once item dragged out, but this event never occurs >_<
What could be the reason and how to fix or bypass this?

Comment: I made `AllowDrop` to `True` and it enters.

Comment: Huh... never though there are any relations between those. Made it as answer, so I could accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make `AllowDrop = True;`